# How can I reformat xml data with fme?

Tags: fme-form, xml, relates

I am reading xml data with FME 2014 and attempting to rebuild a relational database model. I have an xml object "element " which has an m:m relationship with object "type". The xml looks like this...

```
<element id="194070" >
  <types>
    <type id="445"/>
    <type id="643"/>
  </types>
</element>
```

Using fme I can flatten the xml and recreate a table which looks like this...

```
element.id | type.id.1 | type.id.2
194070          445         643
```

But in order to build a association table for the m:m relationship I need this;

```
element.id | type.id
194070          445
194070          643
```

Can anyone offer a way to create this association table using fme transformers?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a separate feature per record. An FME list is probably the best way to go. Try using the ListPopulator transformer to create the list, then the ListExploder transformer to explode it into multiple features.

Comment: Having said that, I'm sure there must be a way to do this directly with the XML Reader/Transformers. I'll investigate.